# Query result has repeated data from two joined tables and thoughts on optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 huge BigQuery tables(say ~20 GB each) from which I would like to find two sessions which had the same tags from different employers. In other words, find all sessions whose tags(except anything that has "default" in it) match with other sessions that were made by employees of another employer(s).

Since there's no BigQuery fiddle, I replicated the problem in MySQL. Below query I wrote gets the data, but has two major problems:

1. Is way too slow(of course because of 2 select all data queries).
2. Repeats the sessions data of two such matching sessions. Notice all session tags have repeated data of first_session_id

The pressing problem is the slowness. I am running this query in a daemon job from ruby/rake script that generates reports, the issue is the connection is timing out and results in no data even for setting it up for 5 retries.

Increasing the timeout didn't help either and I am wondering if there's any other way to write this query.

Here is the  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b93f6e/8) for detailed inspection:

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE session_infos(
  session_uuid varchar(255),
  session_tag varchar(255) DEFAULT 'default'
);

CREATE TABLE employee_sessions(
  employer_id int(11),
  employee_id int(11),
  session_uuid varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO session_infos
          (session_uuid, session_tag)
        VALUES
          ('dcv3erwfw', 'search'),
          ('aefd4erww', 'default_search'),
          ('slkjdvbh8', 'game_default'),
          ('kjdshvo93', 'client'),
          ('sdvife333', 'client'),
          ('dvvnjer54', 'search'),
          ('lsdvkJHd=', 'fiddle'),
          ('Udbwjw=23', 'fiddle'),
          ('jKHDJFWJ1', 'search');

INSERT INTO employee_sessions
      (employer_id, employee_id, session_uuid)
    VALUES
      (1, 1, 'dcv3erwfw'),
      (1, 2, 'aefd4erww'),
      (2, 1, 'slkjdvbh8'),
      (2, 1, 'kjdshvo93'),
      (1, 2, 'sdvife333'),
      (2, 2, 'dvvnjer54'),
      (3, 1, 'lsdvkJHd='),
      (2, 1, 'Udbwjw=23'),
      (4, 1, 'jKHDJFWJ1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  first_table.session_tag AS session_tag,
  first_table.sid AS first_session_id,
  second_table.sid AS second_session_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      si.session_tag AS session_tag,
      es.employer_id AS employer_id,
      es.session_uuid AS sid
    FROM session_infos AS si
    JOIN employee_sessions AS es
      ON es.session_uuid = si.session_uuid
    WHERE
      si.session_tag NOT LIKE '%default%'
  ) first_table
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      ssi.session_tag AS session_tag,
      ses.employer_id AS employer_id,
      ses.session_uuid AS sid
    FROM session_infos AS ssi
    JOIN employee_sessions AS ses
      ON ses.session_uuid = ssi.session_uuid
    WHERE
      ssi.session_tag NOT LIKE '%default%'
  ) second_table
  ON first_table.session_tag = second_table.session_tag
  WHERE first_table.employer_id != second_table.employer_id
--   GROUP BY first_table.session_tag, first_table.sid, second_table.sid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b93f6e/8/0)**:

```
| session_tag | first_session_id | second_session_id |
|-------------|------------------|-------------------|
|      search |        dcv3erwfw |         dvvnjer54 |
|      search |        dcv3erwfw |         jKHDJFWJ1 |
|      client |        kjdshvo93 |         sdvife333 |
|      client |        sdvife333 |         kjdshvo93 |
|      search |        dvvnjer54 |         dcv3erwfw |
|      search |        dvvnjer54 |         jKHDJFWJ1 |
|      fiddle |        lsdvkJHd= |         Udbwjw=23 |
|      fiddle |        Udbwjw=23 |         lsdvkJHd= |
|      search |        jKHDJFWJ1 |         dcv3erwfw |
|      search |        jKHDJFWJ1 |         dvvnjer54 |
```

Comment: Note that '%...' cannot use an index, so if that's a realistic scenario, then that's always going to be slow

Comment: Are the BigQuery tables indexed? Can you update the question to show any indexes?

Comment: Adding to @Strawberry's comment: you could check if a HAVING clause is a more efficient way of getting rid of default sessions.

Comment: @Strawberry : Problem is "default" could be anywhere in the tag and tags are generated randomly, which lowers the chances of grepping all possible "default" types and excluding them explicitly by hardcoding in the query, hence the like '%..'.

Comment: @DagSondreHansen : Tables in BigQuery aren't indexed and I just have the read permissions, so can not update them. Besides the data is synced to them from a mongoDB database periodically which means some of the columns may or may not have the data, so do not even have "NOT NULL" constraint.

Comment: @Surya you could remove ssi.session_tag NOT LIKE '%default%' from the definition of second_table. Any *default* session_tags will be ignored thanks to this test first_table.session_tag = second_table.session_tag since first_table is already excluding them. And like Dag Sondre Hansen said depending on the volume of *default* sessions it could be more efficient to use having on the result instead of the two NOT LIKE '%default%'.